# How to automate employees schedule

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to create an excel file with

- all my employees (rows from 1 to 24)
- and all the workdays (from columns B (01.0.2021) to NB (31.12.2021))

Every workday I need 5 employees on phone duty so i would like to have some ramdomizer that chooses 5 people for that day. The next day the randomizer chooses another set of 5 people but the 5 from yestersday should be excluded and so on and so forth.

ideally it will generate a sort of calender where people can see if they are on phone duty or not. somewhat like in the picture (the picture shows our current situation, not automated/randomized)

[image: Current Excel]

I hope my question is understandable. I'm not very good with excel and dont even know where to start.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The procedure you described may pick some employee(s) excessively many times, some other(s) only few times. It may happen some employee is picked 0 times. Pure luck. Are you OK with this? Or is there a constraint (condition) to prevent this?

Comment: do not do it randomly, do it routinely, 1 its fair, 2 its easier to create and manage

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/1261657/john-artnet and https://superuser.com/users/1267189/john-artnet.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: P.S. If you plan on being a member of the Stack Exchange community, I suggest that you *register* your merged account.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, where randomizing may not be the most fair option out there. If you still want to pursue, then here's one idea to get you started and is reasonably fair. My excel does not support dynamic array functions (formulas such as sortby, sequence and randarray), so I'm using the old-fashioned method of randomizing numbers below.

In my data, column A is the employee id and column B is a random number.

```
Cell B2 formula: =RAND()
```

Copy the formula down and then create filters on columns A and B. **[NOTE: The Random number will change during every excel calculation. Don't worry about that now.]**

Next, column D represents your Day of Week (assuming your work week is 5 days such as Monday through Friday), repeated 5 times (the number of employees you need on phones each day).

Columns E through N represent the first 10 weeks of your calendar. Expand as needed.

**Here's the process:**

Sort column B (smallest to largest is fine) and then copy the cells A2:A25 and paste in cells E2:E25. Repeat this process (sort, copy, paste) until you have all your weeks filled in. We're not populating the final Friday row yet because you only have 24 employees to fill 25 spots. We'll fix this next.

Next, we need to fill that 5th spot for each Friday. In row 27, we're going to randomly select an employee who was on the phones during Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday of that week.

```
Cell E27 formula: =RANDBETWEEN(MIN(E2:E16),MAX(E2:E16))
```

Copy the formula across to populate all weeks. Now, we're going to copy E27 through N27 and paste-as-special-values into E26 through N26. The paste-as-special is important so that we remove formulas in our row 26 values. Now you have that 5th spot filled with someone who was on the phones earlier in the week (excluding Thursday).

Lastly, if you want to confirm that nobody has a significant more number of days, you can do a countif formula for each employee. In column Q, we're counting the number of times the employee appears in our schedule. It's not perfect, as some have 12. Maybe it will smooth out as your fill an entire year, not sure.

```
Cell Q2 formula: =COUNTIF($E$2:$N$26,P2)
```

We now have a schedule in cells D1:N26. You can use simple reference formulas to populate your calendar.

[image]